# Comparing date in one row to date in subsequent row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm trying to drop rows of a dataframe based on whether they are duplicates, and always keep the more recent of the rows. This would be simple using `df.drop_duplicates()`, however I also need to apply a `timedelta`. The row is to be considered a duplicate if the `EndDate` column is less than 182 days earlier than that of another row with the same ID.

This table shows the rows that I need to drop in the `Duplicate` column.

```
   ID   EndDate             Duplicate
0  A    2008-07-31 00:00:00 True
1  A    2008-09-31 00:00:00 False   
2  A    2009-07-31 00:00:00 False
3  A    2010-03-31 00:00:00 False
4  B    2008-07-31 00:00:00 False
5  B    2009-05-31 00:00:00 True
6  B    2009-07-31 00:00:00 False
```

The input data is not sorted but it seems that right approach is to sort by `ID` and by `EndDate` and then test each row against the next row. I think I can do this by looping through the rows, but the dataset is relatively large so is there a more efficient way of doing this in `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the following code to work, but I'm sure it could be improved.

```
df = df.sort(['ID','EndDate'])
df['Duplicate'] = (df['EndDate'].shift(-1) - df['EndDate']) - datetime.timedelta(182) < 0
df['Duplicate'] = df['Duplicate'] & (df['ID'].shift(-1) == df['ID'])
df = df[df['Duplicate'] == False]
```